# including php in <noscript> tag

Tags: php

Is it possible to include a php file in a `<noscript>` tag ?......to show if javascript is disabled?

Comment: why does PHP need to know if javascript is disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible for your server-side PHP code to find out whether Javascript is disabled.

If you put PHP code inside a `<noscript>` tag, it will always execute, whether Javascript is enabled or not.  However, the code's output will only be visible if Javascript is disabled.

You might want to use Javascript to redirect to a separate page.

Comment: i just want to include a php file if javascript is disable

Comment: The beauty of this is that if all you want is whether the output is to be visible, this is great ;-) +1

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to include a PHP file if no JavaScript was enabled would probably be this:

```
<noscript><iframe src="your_php_file.php"></iframe></noscript>
```

(not sure if I would use that myself though)

Comment: This worked great for my purposes (adding server side google analytics tracking: http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/).  I don't think that iframes are ALWAYS bad.  Just sometimes people use them for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 6):

Let me suggest that you read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973141/how-do-i-insert-a-variable-into-jquery/1973146#1973146). It explains how PHP actually works. The PHP code is ran before the browser ever gets it.

A request works like this

**Browser Asks for a Webpage**

**The Web Server Runs the PHP Code**
*The web server looks through the file that it is about to send to the browser and looks for PHP code. It then interprets the PHP code and makes a page.*

**The Browser Reads the Output**
*The browser reads through the HTML and Javascript code that is outputted by the webserver*

PHP is never actually ran on the browser, so it has no idea about the prescence of Javascript.