# Can we use php in <noscript> tag? Will the code validate?

Tags: php, html, noscript

Is it correct and valid to use something like this:

```
<noscript>
<?php require_once 'somefile.php'; ?>
</noscript>
```

I've been searching for this answer a lot but unfortunately not much luck. Here is a quote from one of the answers by @SLaks on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989440/including-php-in-noscript-tag).

> "If you put PHP code inside a  tag, it will always execute,
>   whether Javascript is enabled or not. However, the code's output will
>   only be visible if Javascript is disabled."

However I am not very clear if it is valid to use `php` within a `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: You can use PHP in any tag - PHP runs at server side.

Comment: Yes it is valid. But like what you quoted. The php content will not show if `Javascript` is `disabled`.

Comment: `<noscript>` is a very binary approach to dealing with the possibility of JavaScript failing, generally speaking, you should avoid it and 
follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP operates on a stream of text. It doesn't care what the text is. It is either just outputting the input or (when inside a `<?php` section) running PHP. It doesn't know about HTML.

Validity (in this context) only matters in the context of the generated HTML. The HTML will be valid if the PHP outputs valid content, and that will depend on what `require_once 'somefile.php';` outputs.

Comment: Yes you are correct. In that `somefile.php` I am actually displaying a simple 'Javascript Disablled' message to the user along with an option for him to enable it if he wants to or else he can clink on a link which will take him to a non-javascript version of the site. Something similar to what Google does it on it's Gmail site. I am styling this page with some css for neatness hence wanted to take the code to a separate file so that it does not make my code untidy.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is. `<noscript>` is evaluated client side, after PHP preprocessing. So whatever you put in your `somefile.php`, it will be processed, and then the result sent to the client inside the `<noscript>` tag. However, as said by Slaks, the generated output won't be displayed until JS is disabled.

The way you include PHP in your pages has nothing to do with HTML validation, as long as the generated page is valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Oh course you can. Noscript is designed to be used when user has disabled JavaScript, so why not? But be aware that it will always executed while rendering page. Almost all users on the Internet use JS, so it can be a little overhead.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid to use PHP in the  tag - PHP is evaluated on the server, and not send to the client.